# Mysql Group by taking 8 seconds or more on simple query

Tags: mysql

My table is below (have 1.2 million rows),
[image]

My query is below taking 8 seconds is more even if when I remove where query,

```
 select `online_user_log`.`id` AS `id`,`online_user_log`.`abone_no` AS
`abone_no`,`online_user_log`.`kategori` AS
 `kategori`,`online_user_log`.`islem_detay` AS
 `islem_detay`,`online_user_log`.`date` AS `date` from `online_user_log`
where `online_user_log`.`kategori` = 'Kurma' or `online_user_log`.`kategori`
 = 'Kapama' group by `online_user_log`.`abone_no`;
```

I have index on `abone_no` column

Phpmyadmin says it takes `0.005 seconds` to take but in my php application and phpmyadmin it takes 8 seconds or more to retrieve data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to provide the php code that runs for 8sec.

Comment: just executing raw query I provided on the question.

Comment: indexes? `explain`? `ddl`? i think a lot need to be factored in, really.

Comment: As an aside you should not be using group by without any aggregate functions..https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: why uses a group by?

Comment: it doesn't change the result even if I use it with aggregate functions, slow as it is.

`select MAX(date) from online_user_log group by abone_no;`

Comment: 'just executing raw query I provided on the question' - if phpmyadmin is performant and php isn't then the fault is in php or the network speed.

Comment: Phpmyadmin is also slow, it retrieves the record in 8 seconds but it says  `Query was successful. It took 0.0172 seconds` but I wait more than 8 seconds.

Comment: How many rows does your query return?

Comment: *it says Query was successful. It took 0.0172 seconds but I wait more than 8 seconds* - so the problematic point is not a query. Network transfer, client rendering, antiviral checking and so on... search the problem out of MySQL.